# Download file from GCF function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, puppeteer

I am running a NodeJS script using puppeteer in my local machine to download some assets from Internet. I wanted that script to to be running as Google Cloud function.

I just wanted to know, is there any local space associated with GFC where we can save this files and can be accessed later or can we specify any cloud storage bucket URL where this download can save.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const { program } = require('commander');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

program
    .option('-e, --email <email>', 'Login Email Address', process.env.LOOKER_EMAIL || '')
    .option('-p, --password <password>', 'Login Password', process.env.LOOKER_PASSWORD || '')
    .option('-d, --dashboard <id>', 'Dashboard To Download');
program.parse(process.argv);

const fs = require('fs');
const basePath = 'C:\\card\\'

(async () => {

    const loginEmail = program.email;
    const loginPassword = program.password;
    const dashboardId = program.dashboard;

    // used puppeteer to download some files

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    })

    let pages = await browser.pages();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
    await page.goto(loginUrl);
    await page.waitForSelector(loginEmailSelector);
    await page.type(loginEmailSelector, loginEmail);
    await page.type(loginPasswordSelector, loginPassword);
    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation(),
        page.click(loginButtonSelector)
    ]);

    await page.goto(`https://somewebsite/${dashboardId}`);
    await page.waitForSelector(menuSelector, {
        visible: true
    });
    await page.click(menuSelector);
    await page.waitForSelector(downloadSelector, {
        visible: true
    });


    const ts = Date.now()
    const downloadLoc = basePath + ts + '\\'
    console.log('downloadLoc ', downloadLoc)
    await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
        behavior: 'allow',
        downloadPath: downloadLoc 
    })
    console.log(`your file's on the way!`)


})();
```

So here in the script I am just downloading the file in C drive, I wanted this to store in some cloud storage if possible, Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Google Cloud Functions have a tmp directory. However, this is a ram device and not a storage device. Why do you want to pay for the CPU time, memory and network bandwidth to download/upload using Cloud Functions? Cloud Functions works best for event type designs and not as a data transfer vehicle.

Comment: Okay, Thanks John. We just wanted our script to be running as Cloud functions as we didn't have Node server yet. So we just wanted one functionality, this one so thought this would be quick to setup. Anyways what can you suggest other then Google cloud function ?

Comment: Is your goal is to scrape assets located on the Internet and store them in Cloud Storage? Provide more information about the objects, their size, frequency of transfers, etc. What have you tried? What problems are you having? Edit your question with details. Read this to help you create a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Concept of Cloud Function assumes that code should be stateless, which means that any data should be stored outside, although there is possibility to use `/tmp` directory, but this is only for temporary purposes. Recommended solution is Cloud Storage ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-temp-files)).

However not only Cloud Storage can be used to keep the state. This would be the best in case of binary objects, meaning files.

On the other hand, if those files contain data, you could try to choose one of Google NoSQL databases like [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore), [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#in_datastore_mode) (actually Firestore in Datastore mode) and [Firebase Realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). All of them have nice API for many languages, including of course `node.js`. Additionally, if you plan to create larger solutions, it's possible to even use [BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable) for massive data and [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/introduction) if you need analytics. All of this depends on what you need.

Nice and very convenient in above mentioned Google API's is that in Cloud Functions there is no need to authenticate to the particular products saving a lot of code and resources. All of the solutions are server-less, so you do not have to care about server underneath and scaling when your solution will grow. Also you can get extremely fast network speed between resources when you will do it inside GCP.